# Never can find all of me - What am I?

Tags: riddle, poetry

> I'm only found at the end
>
> But never can you find all of me
>
> I'm the smartest guy around
>
> I know as far as the eye can see
>
> Find me, and you'll sigh in relief
>
> But don't get cocky, your victory is brief
>
> For I'm gone again, I am everywhere
>
> It won't be long before you must find me again
>
> If I'm never found I wait to be discovered
>
> You're looking for me right now, I'm just hidden and covered

What am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you

> The correct answer?

I'm only found at the end

> When you're looking for the answer to something, your search is over when you find it.

But never can you find all of me

> There are an infinite amount of questions, you can't find answers to all of them.

I'm the smartest guy around

> The correct answer is never wrong - I guess this would make it the smartest guy around (if it were a person)

I know as far as the eye can see

> Answers are everywhere - This could also mean that there is an answer to the question: "How far can the eye see?"

Find me, and you'll sigh in relief

> It's a relief to find the correct answer to a hard problem

But don't get cocky, your victory is brief

> Even if a question is answered, there are still many left unanswered.

For I'm gone again, I am everywhere

> Once you find an answer, you often set off searching for another. Answers are everywhere if you know how to find them.

It won't be long before you must find me again

> We are faced with new questions that need answering every day

If I'm never found I wait to be discovered

> If nobody finds an answer, it doesn't stop existing, it just waits to be found

You're looking for me right now, I'm just hidden and covered

> We're looking for the answer to this riddle!

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I would have accepted answer or solution, something close.

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

> full stop

because

> full stop only found at the end of a sentence

Answer (score 2):

Must be

> Horizon

I'm only found at the end
But never can you find all of me
I'm the smartest guy around
I know as far as the eye can see

> Horizon limits the end of our field of vision. Usually most of it is covered by objects around like houses or trees.

Find me, and you'll sigh in relief
But don't get cocky, your victory is brief
For I'm gone again, I am everywhere
It won't be long before you must find me again

> When, for example, hiking you go for the horizon and feel as if reaching it is some kind of victory or checkpoint. The thing is one can never actually make it to the horizon as it moves away while we appoach it. Imagine climbing a mountain which serves as horizon. On top of the montain you'll see another horizon far away.

If I'm never found I wait to be discovered
You're looking for me right now, I'm just hidden and covered

> Horizon won't move away if we just sit around. And we could say it's *waiting* for us. You can usually always see some part of the horizon even if partly hidden behind, as I said before, houses or trees etc.

Answer (score -1):

Are you a

> HINT

I'm only found at the end

> Normally hints are found at the end of the question

But never can you find all of me

> Always only a few hints will be provided and also it will be hidden with spoiler tag

I'm the smartest guy around

> Hints are normally smaller than the question (usually one line)

I know as far as the eye can see

> May be referring to the hint getting visible on hovering the mouse over the spoiler tag

Find me, and you'll sigh in relief

> We feel relieved if we see a helpful hint that can lead us to answer

But don't get cocky, your victory is brief

> Not all the hint will lead us to the answer

For I'm gone again, I am everywhere

> The hint in spoiler tag will be hidden again, if the cursor is out

It won't be long before you must find me again

> It will appear again as soon as you put the cursor in again

If I'm never found I wait to be discovered

> it's about the hidden hints inside the question itself

You're looking for me right now, I'm just hidden and covered

> All of us are looking for a hint to solve this riddle